# How to update a zip file in ssh? (Ubuntu)

Tags: backup, compression, zip

I use zip to backup a website public folder (4 GB zip) daily. Is there a command to update the same zip file without creating from scratch each time?

It should do 3 things:

1. If file exist on zip, skip it.
2. If file doesn't exist on zip, add it.
3. If file was removed from site, remove it from zip too.

I think this will be faster than just zipping every single file from scratch.
If not with zip maybe with another compressing method, speed is priority not compression.

Comment: I'd rsync the folder to your machine, this is exactly meant for your application. It will only transmit the changes with some overhead.

Comment: Hello i'm not sure how to do that from windows without redownloading the entire file each time- But this is also so the server don't spend so much time recreating the backup file.

Comment: With rsync, you would sync the folder uncompressed to your pc, and then create an archive from that. The result will be, you only download new/changed files.

Comment: Oh yeah goodsync does that as well. It was just simpler to download 1 file.

Comment: Zipping 4Gb is really fast today. But transmitting it takes much longer. So with rsync you only transmit the changes. On your local host, you can run 7zip with update as parameter, which will still save you from transmitting all files.